# Buscando palavra dentro de texto do Array PHP

Tags: php

tenho um array com palavras dentro, separadas por ; e preciso localizar 
determinada palavra para realizar o unset nele.

```
$element = ';nao;';
$text = array('conjunto;palavras;nao','palavras;sim','nao;texto','texto;dividido;nao');

$key = array_search($element, $text);
if($key!==false){
    unset($text[$key]);
}
```

Utilizei o código acima, porém ele apenas consegue localizar se a palavra estiver sozinha sem as outras dentro da array.

Comment: Para este exemplo seriam excluídas todos os valores que possuem o "nao"? Ou seja, o resultado seria `['palavras;sim']`?

Comment: Boa tarde. Pra que você precisa disso?

Comment: Os que devem permanecer são os que tiverem ;sim; dentro da array. Eu preciso para limpar o pdf que recebo do detran e transformar em CSV, porém preciso apenas dos arrays que tiverem sim para poder atualizar a base de dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeira dica é evitar ao máximo o uso do `unset` a menos que seja necessário, pois você perde o valor original da sua variável e isso pode complicar o processo de depuração durante a manutenção - você não consegue comparar entrada/saída pois você modifica um para obter o outro. O que você quer fazer é filtrar os valores do *array*, então de cara já temos uma função para utilizar: [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php). Cada valor do *array* é um conjunto de palavras separadas por ponto-e-vírgula, então teremos que separá-las em uma lista de palavras:

```
$result = array_filter($text, function ($setence) use ($element) {
    return !in_array($element, explode(';', $setence));
});
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-394557) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/RFO86Z)</sup>

Com isso, o resultado seria:

```
Array
(
    [1] => palavras;sim
)
```

Mas isso quando for buscado a palavra `"nao"`, sem os caracteres em torno da palavra, que não deveriam pertencer à ela dado que são separadores.

Caso queira evitar a alocação de memória que a função `explode` intrinsecamente fará para armazenar as substrings em memória, você pode utilizar a `strpos` (ou `mb_strpos` se for trabalhar com multi bytes) tratando as situações em que a palavra pode começar ou encerrar com a palavra buscada adicionando o caractere separador antes e depois do texto:

```
$result = array_filter($text, function ($setence) use ($element) {
    return strpos(";{$setence};", ";{$element};") === false;
});
```

Produzindo o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Realmente o unset me deixava buracos na lista de arrays, dessa maneira com o strpos funcionou, eu fiz um foreach pegando array por array e usava o strpos, os que não tinham;nao; eu montei uma array com eles.

Answer (score -1):

```
$element = ';nao;';
$text = array('conjunto;palavras;nao','palavras;sim','nao;texto','texto;dividido;nao');

foreach ($text as $key => $value) {
    $pos = strpos($value, $element);

    if ($pos !== false) {
        unset($text[$key]);
    }
}
```

A sua procura ";nao;" não vai achar nenhum resultado porque nesse seu array não tem um não com ; no começo e fim, então procure por ";nao" ou "nao;".

Ou modifique o exemplo para aceitar os dois

Comment: Forçar a busca adicionando o caractere separador na string não faz sentido e gera efeitos colaterais. Se buscar por `nao;` poderá remover itens que possuam palavras terminadas em `nao` indevidamente, tal como `anao;sim`; da mesma forma que se buscar por `;nao` removeria termos iniciados em `nao`, como `sim;naomi`